# When to use choose over, between, among and from?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, tenses

I am confused about when to use the following examples(in which situations)? Could you clarify these examples for me?

1. Choose something over something.
2. Choose something between something.
3. Choose something among something.
4. Choose something from something.

Answer (score 7):

1. Choose something over something: When you prefer X over Y
2. Choose something between something: When you choose between two items (only).
3. Choose something among something: When you choose among more than two items.
4. Choose something from something: When you segregated and choose things based on a criteria.